# Xcode Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GameStream"

Tags: objective-c, xcode, xcode6

I'm trying to build & run a objective C Project on Xcode 6.4 and getting the following error and build failes

**Apple Mach-O Linker Error "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GameStream", referenced from:**

```
    Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
      "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GameStream", referenced from:
          objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
          objc-class-ref in GamePlayViewController.o
      "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GameStreamSliderBar", referenced from:
          objc-class-ref in MainMenuViewController.o
    ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
    clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I have **GameStream.framework** in the Link binary With Libraries under Build Phases.

Under Valid Architectures I have **armv7 armv7s arm64**.

Comment: It's complaining that it can't find compatible symbols for you trying to run it in the simulator.  Did you build GameStream yourself from source or did you download the `.framework` folder from somewhere?

Comment: Does the framework support 64 bit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having checked the framework, it's been last updated since 2013 so I'd say it's unfortunately because of the framework.

Comment: In build phases I changed "Build Active Architecture Only" to No and removed arm64 from Valid Architectures and it worked!
But now sure what are the side effects of this.

Comment: What I can tell is that from now on if you're to submit your app to the App store it'll need to support 64bit.